# Calculate the convolution of two functions

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution, signal-processing

I've been given a problem, to calculate the convolution of the functions $h$ and $x$ where:

$$h(t) = \begin{cases}t  &\text{if $0<t<2T$}\\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
     $$x(t) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $0<t<T$}\\ 0 &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
($T$ is a parameter).

How can I do that? A detailed explanation/solution is preferred. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried applying the definition of convolution?

Comment: The convolution $h*x$ of $h$ and $x$ is defined by $(h*x)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(z)x(t-z)dz$. (It is commuative, and so also equal to $(x*h)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t-z)x(z)dz$.)

Comment: In order to compute $f:=h*x$, you can derivate it using the expression $f'=h'*x$, but beware $h'$ is the characteristic function of interval [0,2a] **plus** 2T times a Dirac in t=2T. Then, once the convolution has been done, you integrate the result.

Comment: I tried to use the definition of convolution but I have no Idea how to substitute both of the functions in the equation. Could someone post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computation of this convolution $g:=x*h$ is quite tedious since both $x$ and $h$ are defined piecewise. Formally $g$ is defined by
$$g(t):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t-\tau)h(\tau)\>d\tau\qquad(-\infty<t<\infty)\ .$$
Now $x(t-\tau)\ne0$ (in fact $=1$) only if $0<t-\tau<T$, or $t-T<\tau<t$. It follows that we may write
$$g(t)=\int_{t-T}^t h(\tau)\>d\tau\qquad(-\infty<t<\infty)\ .$$
We now have to distinguish cases according to how the interval of integration $[t-T, t]$ intersects the interval $[0,2T]$ where $h$ has an "interesting definition". From a figure we deduce that we have to distinguish the following five cases:
$$\eqalign{g(t)&=\int_{t-T}^t 0\>d\tau=0\qquad(t<0)\ ,\cr
g(t)&=\int_{0}^t \tau\>d\tau=\ldots\qquad(0<t<T)\ ,\cr
g(t)&=\int_{t-T}^t \tau\>d\tau=\ldots\qquad(T<t<2T)\ ,\cr
g(t)&=\int_{t-T}^{2T} \tau\>d\tau=\ldots\qquad(2T<t<3T)\ ,\cr
g(t)&=\int_{t-T}^t 0\>d\tau=0\qquad(t>3T)\ .\cr}$$
I leave it to you to compute the three nonzero integrals. In the end you should obtain a  function $t\mapsto g(t)$ which is continuous on all of ${\mathbb R}$.